# Use of Malloc in C and pointer member error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, member

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Album {
    char* title;
} 

int main(){
    int i, size;

    struct Album* pAlbum;
    printf("Enter the number of album: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);

    pAlbum = malloc(sizeof(pAlbum) * size);

    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("Enter the album title: ");
        scanf_s("%p", pAlbum[i].title);
    }

    free(pAlbum);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to let the user enter the title for as many albums as they want. The error is that scanf only comes up once for `pAlbump[i].tittle` for the loop. I'm i allocating the memory incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pAlbum = malloc(sizeof(pAlbum) * size);
```

This allocates `size` **pointers**. But you wish to allocate `size` **structs**.

Your allocation should therefore be

```
pAlbum = malloc(sizeof(*pAlbum) * size);
```

or

```
pAlbum = malloc(sizeof(struct Album) * size);
```

or

```
pAlbum = calloc(size, sizeof(struct Album));
```

Once you've dealt with that, you will need to allocate memory to store each string in the struct. That's going to need separate calls to `malloc`.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
    printf("Enter the album title: ");
    pAlbum[i].title = malloc(...); // you need to decide how much to allocate
    scanf_s("%s", pAlbum[i].title); // hmm, this simply begs a buffer overrun ...
}
```

And then you'd need to free each of the `title` strings that you allocated in that loop before freeing the array of structs.

Answer (score 4):

Before using data member title of the structure in statement

```
    scanf_s("%p", pAlbum[i].title);
```

you have to allocate memory that will be pointed to by this data member and where you are going to store entered data.

And you have to use tag struct before  name Album in statement

```
pAlbum = malloc(sizeof( struct pAlbum) * size);
```

And instead type specifier `"%p"` you have to use `%s` that to enter a string.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are not to add extra members to your structure then just pull out the `char*` to the outside and use it. If you want the type to be called Album, you could write `typedef char *Album;`. You are allocating memory to hold pointers to strings but not the memory that holds the actual strings. Your `scanf` uses the wrong format `%p`, use `%s` to read a string of characters; the `scanf` is reading to an unallocated piece of memory so that's going to cause a runtime error.

To allocate memory for `n` items, use `calloc` (for contiguous allocate). `calloc` allocates a block of memory for an array of `n` elements, each of them `elem_size`bytes long.

```
calloc(n, elem_size);
```

You should know how many bytes each title is or use a maximum number of bytes in your code. There exists a function that will take care of the memory allocation for you but it's not part of the standard. It's called `strdup`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either make `title` member an array of fixed size

```
struct Album {
   char title[100];
}
```

and use `scanf_s` this way

```
scanf_s("%99s", pAlbum[i].title, _countof(pAlbum[i].title));
```

Or, use malloc

```
char tmp[100];
if (scanf_s("%99s", tmp, _countof(tmp)) == 1)  
    pAlbum[i].title = strdup(tmp);
```

Also, to allocate `size` structs, do as David Heffernan said.

Comment: Weird. When i fix the problem as told by everyone it works with scanf, but when i use scanf_s(because compiler gave me a warning and said i should use scanf_s), i can only loop scanf_s once so the user can only enter one title and no more.

Comment: @Denominator This is not right `malloc(sizeof(char[100]))` just `malloc(100)` will do.